# Beamer: bullets appears when item appears

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

I am trying the followin code in beamer

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-slpe}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%               
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
  }

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{onlyenv}<1-7>
 \begin{itemize}
  %&\addtolength{\itemindent}{-0.5cm}
  \item \only<2-7>{text text text text text text} \only<3-7>{text text text text text text.}
 \item \only<4-7>{text text text text text text}\only<5-7>{text text text text text text.}
 \item \only<6-6>{text text text text text text.} \only<7-7>{another text another text another text another text.}
  \end{itemize}
  \end{onlyenv}  
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

The first slide shows the three bullets before the items appear.

[image]

I want the bullet to appear when the item appears. I cannot find any solution in the net. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
\usecolortheme{beaver} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{onlyenv}<1-7>
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<2-7>  \only<2-7>{text text text text text text}           
                            \only<3-7>{text text text text text text.}
                \item<4-7>  \only<4-7>{text text text text text text}           
                            \only<5-7>{text text text text text text.}
                \item<6-7>  \only<6-6>{text text text text text text.} 
                            \only<7-7>{another text another text another text another text.}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{onlyenv}  
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\item<2-7>` and  `\only<2-7>{`. Only `\item<2-7>` works...

Comment: @Bobyandbob At least for the third item it's necessary to replace the text. For the other two, you are right, one could remove the first `\only`